# Where is the 'break even' point for scaling a collection up / down

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've been thinking about scaling my collection up before initiating a large write or bulk import.

However I am struck that I don't know how many RU's it costs to perform the scaling operation.  It's possible that it could cost more to scale up, execute, and back down than it would be to just leave it at a constant level.

Naturally, there are concerns around how long between writes, how long the process takes, etc, but I can't really approach the question without knowing the cost of scaling.  I'm curious if anyone has a policy or rule-of-thumb they use to control this.

Comment: Maybe.  I doubt it though.

Answer (score 2):

The cost of the scaling operation itself is the same as the cost of updating any other `Resource` in CosmosDB.

What you need to know is that from the `Database` to the `Document` everything inherits from a single type. The `Resource`.

What you are talking about is updating an `Offer` which is the `Resource` that holds the collection's offer data, such as the throughput. Updating the offer costs the same as updating any other document of that size (which would be something around the 5-10 RUs).

Keep in mind however that CosmosDB charges you on an hourly basis based on the maximum provisioned throughput of the collection for that hour. This means that even if you upscale and instantly downscale the throughput, you will still be charged for one hour worth of that maximum throughput.

Comment: Pretty answer,Nick!